# What is benefit of developing webservice using Apache CXF over normal JAX-WS with Java6

Tags: cxf

Can some body expalain what is the benefit of developing JAX-WS webservice using apache CXF over normal JAX-WS provided by Java 6.

Answer (score 4):

JAX-WS is only the api / specification - to use it you need an implementation.  It can be something like CXF, Axis or the one provided by the application server (JBoss, Weblogic et..).

One advantage of using CXF is that you have more flexibility in terms of deployment. It can be deployed in a web container or you can use an embedded web container and runt it as a stand alone application.

CXF also provides integration with other frameworks like spring.

It also provides tools to work with schema / WSDL etc..

Answer (score 1):

Apache CXF is a open source webservice framework which contains JAX-WE and JAX-RS and also it helps to integrate with spring framework

CXF Supports

1) XML , JSON Format

2)JAXB Data Binding

3) SAOP ,REST,HTTP protocal binding

Answer (score 0):

I have recently completed the web service implementation with JAX-WS using reference implementation apache-cxf. And I found with CXF - integration with Spring is very easy. Moreover, It provides various features like:

1. Customization of Logging features
2. Inbound and Outbound interceptor
3. Application Level security
4. Easy Exception handling using custom Fault.

For more detail, if you want, please checkout this link: http://predic8.com/axis2-cxf-jax-ws-comparison.htm

And, I read above link, its preety helpful for me.

Thanks !